# Правильная процедура мока статических методов

Tags: java, junit, mockito, mock

Стоит задача протестировать поведение некоторого метода некоторого класса. Тестовых кейсов более 70 штук. Проблема в том, что часть параметров этот класс получает из неких статических методов различных контекстов, хелперов и прочей лабуды. Соответственно, все эти параметры необходимо как-то замокать.
Я использовал примерно такой вариант:

```
PowerMock.mockStatic(SomeHelper.class)
when(SomeHelper.getSomeTestData()).thenReturn(mockedTestData)
```

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что только в первом тесте статический метод возвращает корректные параметры. В последующих тестах врзвращает те же самые параметры из первого теста.
Нагуглил следующее решение - перед каждым тестом ставить аннотацию:

```
@PrepareForTest(SomeHelper.class)
```

Теперь статический класс вроде бы стал возвращать корректные параметры, но в какой-то момент стали сыпаться

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: внутренняя память израсходована

И это при ~17 написанных тестов, а у меня их должно быть более 70.
Может у кого-то есть опыт корректного мокирования статических методов?

Аналогичная проблема с `Powermock.whenNew()` - мне нужно замокать создание объекта определенного сервиса в тестируемом классе, так как он тоже предоставляет некоторые параметры для корректной работы тестируемого метода.

Comment: вы можете использовать `any()` или `@spy`

Comment: мм, у меня в каждом тесте свои тестовые данные. Я не могу передать их все сразу через такую цепочку.